# PHPUnit can not connect to CodeIgniter DB with provided setting

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpunit

Recently i used a trick that from source `https://github.com/fmalk/codeigniter-phpunit` to integrate PHPUnit test to CodeIgniter. I've done everything as in the instruction, but when i start running the test, it gives me a error `Unable to connect to the database server using the provided settings.`
In database.php , all the settings are right, for both testing and default because they are the same. I can run my project via localhost and it works fine.
Here is my setting:

```
$db['testing']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['testing']['username'] = 'root';
$db['testing']['password'] = 'motngaycu';
$db['testing']['database'] = 'work_is_easy';
$db['testing']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['testing']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['testing']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['testing']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['testing']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['testing']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['testing']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['testing']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['testing']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['testing']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['testing']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of that CI project.
Your `php.ini` CLI settings might be different from when you run under a web server: please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181222/php-mysql-connect-wont-work-via-command-line) for clues.